# How should I use shutil.make_archive to zip my data?

Tags: python, zip, dir, shutil

I'm trying to zip results from folder sam > pythonresults > today to folder sam > summary > today

I have bunch of txt files present in sam > pythonresults > today (today folder has 10 text files)

I was going through some documentation which has discussed it but I'm not able to understand how this has to be done.

```
shutil.make_archive(target_dir, "zip", root_dir=compressed)
```

can anyone tell me?
In what format I should provide the path of target_dir and root_dir?

Thanks

I tried :

```
archive_name = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', archive_dir))
root_dir_name = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', root_dir))
shutil.make_archive(archive_name, 'zip', root_dir_name)
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
  File "c:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 527, in make_archive
    os.chdir(root_dir)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:/Users/sam\\summary\\today'
```

Comment: Does `~/summary` exist? If not, you're just missing an `os.mkdirs`.

Comment: What's in `archive_dir`? Does it end in a slash or backslash? And are you trying to create an archive in the `~/summary/today` directory (if so, with what name?), or an archive named `today.zip` in the `~/summary` directory?

Comment: @abarnert archive_dir exists hence I'm not making it again.
it's string summary\today

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're missing the actual _name_ part of your `archive_name`. You're just giving it the path to a directory. What happens is you replace that first `join` with `os.path.join('~', archive_dir, 'archive')`?

Comment: According to the [`shutil.make_archive()` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations) the first argument, _`base_name`_ "is the name of the file to create, including the path, minus any format-specific extension", _not_ the name of a directory as you seem to be doing.